# Ionic angular cordova upload audio File to server

Tags: angular, file, cordova, ionic-framework, httprequest

I'm trying to upload an audio file, created with MediaObject, to the server using Ionic, Angular, Cordova. I'm using the Native File plugin and httpClient from @angular/common/http.

I can't get the file on the server side with PHP $_FILES('audio'). I can't detect what I'm doing wrong. Maybe I need to get the file with file.getFile() ? but I can't get it to work.

I already try "multipart/form-data", "file", "false", "undefined" as "Content-Type" but cannot get the file on server side.

Here is my code, I have all the necessary includes and there are no errors in the console.

```
audio: MediaObject;
audioFile: FileEntry;
fileName: string;


startAudio() {
    
    this.fileName = "audio" + Date.now() + ".mp3";
    this.audio = this.media.create(this.fileName);
    this.audio.startRecord();
  
}

async finishAudio(){
    this.audio.stopRecord();
    
    const formAudio = new FormData();
    
    //this.audioFile = this.file.getFile(this.file.externalDataDirectory.replace(/file:\/\//g, ''), this.fileName, { create: false });
    
    const buffer = await this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file.externalDataDirectory, this.fileName);   
    const fileBlob = new Blob([buffer], {type:'audio/mp3'});
    console.log(buffer);
    formAudio.append("audio", fileBlob, this.fileName);
    this.responseAudioForm = this.audioFormService.postFile(formArchivo);
            this.responseAudioForm.subscribe(data =>{
                this.responseDataAudioForm = data ;
                let title = data.title;
                let message = data.message;
    });
}


/* AudioFormService */

postFile(formData:FormData): Observable<any>{
        //console.log(fields);
        const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
            })
        }
        
        this.presentLoading();
        return this.httpClient.post(this.apiUpdateURL, formData, httpOptions)
            .pipe(
                map(results => {
                    console.log("RAW:",results);
                    this.dismissLoading();
                    this.showToast();
                    return results;
                }),
                catchError(err => {
                    console.log("Handling error:", err);
                    this.showAlert(err.statusText,err.name,err.message);
                    return throwError(err);
                }),
                catchError(err => {
                    console.log("caught rethrown:", err);
                    return of([]);
                })
            );
}
```

**Solution. in case it can help someone**

```
audio: MediaObject;
audioFile: FileEntry;

responseAyudaForm: Observable<any>;
responseDataAyudaForm: any = [];

// Start audio recording
async startAudio() {
    
    var path: string = "";
    if(this.platform.is("ios")){
        
      path = this.file.tempDirectory;
      this.fileName = new Date().getTime() + ".mp3";
      this.audioFile = await this.file.createFile(path, this.fileName, true);
      this.audio = this.media.create(this.file.tempDirectory.replace(/^file:\/\//, '') + this.fileName);
      
    } else {
        
      path = this.file.externalDataDirectory;
      this.fileName = new Date().getTime() + ".mp3";
      this.audioFile = await this.file.createFile(path, this.fileName, true);
      this.audio = this.media.create(this.audioFile.nativeURL);
    
    }

    this.audio.startRecord();
    console.log("Record Start");
}


// Stop audio recording and upload file to server
async finishAudio() {
    
    this.audio.stopRecord();
    console.log("Stop Recording");
    
    // Upload the new recording
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200));
    
    console.log("Start Blob convertion");  
    const blob = await this.getBlobFromFileEntry(this.audioFile);
    console.log("Finish Blob convertion");

    const formFile = new FormData();
        
    formFile.append("audio", blob, this.fileName);
      
    this.responseAyudaForm = this.ayudaService.postFile(formFile);
    this.responseAyudaForm.subscribe(data =>{
        this.responseDataAyudaForm = data ;
        let title = data.title;
        let message = data.message;
    });
  
}

getBlobFromFileEntry(fileEntry: FileEntry): Promise<Blob> {
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        
      fileEntry.file((file) => {
          
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(e) {
            
          
          try {
              
            const { result: buffer } = e.target
            const blob = new Blob( [new Uint8Array(buffer as any)], { type: 'audio/mp3' } /* or file.type */
            
            );
            console.log(blob);
            resolve(blob);
            
          } catch (error) { reject(error); }
          
        };
        
        reader.onabort = (ev) => reject(ev);
        reader.onerror = (ev) => reject(ev);
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        
      }, reject)
    });
}

/**
/ AyudaService.postFile()
**/
postFile(formData:FormData): Observable<any>{

    /*const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            "Content-Type": 'file',
        })
    }*/
    
    this.presentLoading();
    return this.httpClient.post(this.apiAudioURL, formData) /* I removed the httpOptions parameter and it worked */
        .pipe(
            map(results => {
                console.log("RAW:",results);
                this.dismissLoading();
                this.showToast();
                return results;
            }),
            catchError(err => {
                console.log("Handling error:", err);
                this.showAlert(err.statusText,err.name,err.message);
                return throwError(err);
            }),
            catchError(err => {
                console.log("Caught Rethrown:", err);
                return of([]);
            })
        );
}
```

Comment: I can suggest you to convert it into base64. I have a working code if you want? I have recently implemented it in an app where users can send voice notes to each other.

Comment: Hi Riya Singh, I finally solved it!!! but your code will be of great help to me if it is possible that you send it!!

Comment: Please can you provide the solution here ? ... are you using cordova plugin file? please can you tell me how?  :'(

Comment: Hi Riya! yes, I'am using de plugin File. I posted the code in the main body.

Comment: Hi! thanks for replying. Is that the cordova-plugin-file ? I am currently using base64 string method for any kind of file upload, I find it more easy to use. But thanks for your solution.

Comment: Hi Riya!! you're welcome, how is your method? to consider in future developments. Thanks

Comment: Hi, for any image or file, I am converting it into a base64 string and sending it to the api file which then compiles it into the file on my server and saves it in a folder there.